# Rearrange matrix in R

Tags: r, sorting

I have got a matrix which I want to be ordered in a different way.

What I have is this matrix:

```
           item    est
1   KT001_Cat1  -0.85
2   KT001_Cat2   0.04
3   KT001_Cat3   0.34
4   KT001_Cat4   0.97
5   KT002_Cat1  -0.81
6   KT002_Cat2  -0.60
7   KT002_Cat3   0.65
8   KT003_Cat1  -0.40
9   KT003_Cat2  -0.19
10  KT003_Cat3   0.56
11  KT004_Cat1  -1.21
```

And what I would like to have is this matrix:

```
     item    est.1  est.2  est.3  est.4
1   KT001    -0.85   0.04   0.34   0.97
2   KT002    -0.81  -0.60   0.65   NA
3   KT003    -0.40  -0.19   0.56   NA
4   KT004    -1.21   NA     NA     NA
```

Does anybody know how I can rearrange my data so that it looks like in the second block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `separate` to separate columns then use `pivot_wider` to spread the data

```
df <- read.table(text = "item    est
1   KT001_Cat1  -0.85
2   KT001_Cat2   0.04
3   KT001_Cat3   0.34
4   KT001_Cat4   0.97
5   KT002_Cat1  -0.81
6   KT002_Cat2  -0.60
7   KT002_Cat3   0.65
8   KT003_Cat1  -0.40
9   KT003_Cat2  -0.19
10  KT003_Cat3   0.56
11  KT004_Cat1  -1.21", header = TRUE)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% separate(item, into = c("item", "Cat"), sep = "_") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Cat, values_from = est)

# A tibble: 4 x 5
  item   Cat1  Cat2  Cat3  Cat4
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 KT001 -0.85  0.04  0.34  0.97
2 KT002 -0.81 -0.6   0.65 NA   
3 KT003 -0.4  -0.19  0.56 NA   
4 KT004 -1.21 NA    NA    NA
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `xtabs` from `base R`

```
xtabs(df$est ~ V1 + V2, read.table(text = df$item, header = FALSE, sep="_"))
```

-output

```
#   V2
#V1       Cat1  Cat2  Cat3  Cat4
#  KT001 -0.85  0.04  0.34  0.97
#  KT002 -0.81 -0.60  0.65  0.00
#  KT003 -0.40 -0.19  0.56  0.00
#  KT004 -1.21  0.00  0.00  0.00
```

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` option

```
> dcast(setDT(df)[, c(tstrsplit(item, "_"), .(est))], V1 ~ V2, fill = 0)
Using 'V3' as value column. Use 'value.var' to override
      V1  Cat1  Cat2 Cat3 Cat4
1: KT001 -0.85  0.04 0.34 0.97
2: KT002 -0.81 -0.60 0.65 0.00
3: KT003 -0.40 -0.19 0.56 0.00
4: KT004 -1.21  0.00 0.00 0.00
```